# Meteor router throws error

Tags: meteor

I'm following the Meteor book and on the routing tutorial. Getting stuck here. Any ideas?

```
mars:meteor_projs mbp$ mrt create test
test: created.

To run your new app:
   cd test
   meteor
mars:meteor_projs mbp$ cd test
mars:test mbp$ mrt add router
✓ router
    tag: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router.git#v0.5.4.1

events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

Any ideas?

Now i get this when i am updating a project with mrt update

```
mars:microscope2 stan$ mrt update
✓ router
    tag: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router.git#v0.5.4.1

events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

Should i remove meteor completely?

Comment: Check if you have the latest version of `meteorite` installed on your system. You may try deleting the `.meteorite` directory in your `home` and rerunning the above commands.

Comment: Hi guys i reinstalled node, meteor and meteorite. looks good so far

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your issue... but everything works on my side:

```
➜  meteor-router-t-e  cd test
➜  test  mrt add router
✓ router
    tag: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router.git#v0.5.4.1
✓ page-js-ie-support
    tag: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-page-js-ie-support.git#v1.3.5
✓ HTML5-History-API
    tag: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-HTML5-History-API.git#v4.0.0

Done installing smart packages

Stand back while Meteorite does its thing

Done installing smart packages

Ok, everything's ready. Here comes Meteor!

router: updating npm dependencies -- connect...
router: A reactive router built on page.js
➜  test
```

My env:

```
➜  meteor-router-t-e  lsb_release --all
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:    13.04
Codename:   raring


➜  meteor-router-t-e  mrt --version
Meteorite version 0.6.15
Release 0.6.6.3
➜  meteor-router-t-e  node --version
v0.10.21
```

What env (OS, meteor, mrt, node) are you using ?

Comment: Hah! I ran the following: mrt --version and it came back with Meteorite version 0.6.14 but it crashed shortly after with events.js:72 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event I guess there is something wrong with meteorite